# Anchor link scroll animation only functions after refreshing (JQuery) on Squarespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace, anchor-scroll

I'm currently building a Squarespace website, and I wanted to add scroll animation with anchor links.

Currently, clicking an anchor link will just immediately snap to that part of the page. Once I refresh, however, it starts working. This seems to only be an issue on Chrome, and I'm not too sure how to fix it, but I highly doubt anyone visiting my page will bother refreshing it.

I'm currently using a code that's supposed to function for all anchor links on the page at once.

Would appreciate any help I can get. Here's the code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
       var target = $(this.hash);
       target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
           scrollTop: target.offset().top
         }, 1000);
         return false;
       }
     }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell without a link, but could be a race between javascript and inbuilt href mechanism on a tag.

you could try replacing

> $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

with

> $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

The issue you describe is caused by [AJAX loading in Squarespace](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading). You can view possible solutions at [this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493314/5338581). Simply put, your options are to disable AJAX or modify your code so that it will work with it, both of which are mentioned at the aforementioned links.