# Is it safe to re-execute an inserted <script> node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss, squarespace

This is a spin-off from [the comments here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493314/624250)

I'm using SquareSpace to build my site, and for some things I like to use their HTML code blocks directly within the page, and include some JavaScript within that (in a `<script></script>`) block. The problem is that SquareSpace's AJAX loading inserts that script node as innerHTML to the code div, so the script doesn't get executed.

So I've added some site-wide code that detects newly inserted SquareSpace code blocks, looks for a `<script>` node within them, and then re-inserts the script node ([using this code)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433770/624250) to execute it. This is what my JavaScript with JQuery code looks like:

```
$(document).bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(e){
  var script_nodes = $(e.target).find(".sqs-block-code").find("script");
  script_nodes.each(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    var code = this.textContent;
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
      $(this).after($(s));
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = code;
      $(this).after($(s));
    }
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

My question is whether this adds a security risk (especially XSS). I thought that maybe it doesn't have *additional* risk, because if an attacker could get a `<script>` node inserted in the first place, then bets are off anyway?

Comment: Depends on what the _"inserted SquareSpace code"_ blocks are/do. For instance if their code allows for user input which gets used in some way. And for whatever reason they forgot to sanitize the user input, that code could introduce a script that you would then be allowed to execute by your code.

Comment: Sorry, yeah let me clarify that. A "SquareSpace code block" is just custom HTML that I write, it's not something that would take user input (unless I write some code that takes user input). My thought was that, if the user has the capability to insert a <script> node into the document (for instance, if I allowed comments with unsanitized HTML), they already have the ability to execute it.