# Squarespace + PayPal - custom form with fee added issue with displaying total

Tags: paypal, squarespace

I'm helping with a Squarespace site and it has a custom form added in code on a particular page. The form collects the payer's info, then can enter any amount in the "Total to charge" field, then it is supposed to display the 2.7% fee. However, I can ONLY get the fee to display if I refresh the page (chrome, safari, either one). [Click here](https://www.christianadopt.org/payments) to see the page...let me know

here is a snippet of code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $amount = $('input[name="amount_1"]');
        var $fee = $("#fee");
        var $total = $("#total");
        var $amount_2 = $("input[name='amount_2']");
        var processing_fee = .027;
        var isCurrency = function (inval) {
            var regex = /^[1-9]\d*(((,\d{3}){1})?(\.\d{0,2})?)$/;
            if (regex.test(inval)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        $amount.on('input propertychange', function () {

            if (isCurrency($amount.val())) {
                var fee = ($amount.val() * processing_fee).toFixed(2);
                var total = (Number(fee) + Number($amount.val())).toFixed(2);
                $fee.text('$' + fee);
                $amount_2.val(fee);
                $total.text('$' + total);
            }
        });
        $amount.on('blur', function () {
            $amount.val($amount.val().replace("$", ""));
            $amount.val(Number($amount.val()).toFixed(2));
            if (!isCurrency($amount.val())) {
                $amount.val("");
            }
        });
        $("#paymentform").validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When a custom script only runs on page refresh, the cause is likely to be [Squarespace's AJAX loading](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading):

> Occasionally, Ajax may conflict with embedded custom code or anchor
> links. Ajax can also interfere with site analytics, logging hits on
> the first page only.

Disabling AJAX is often a simple solution:

> You can disable Ajax in the Style Editor, with some exceptions:
>
> - Ajax can't be disabled in Skye, Foundry, or Tudor.
> - Ajax can't be disabled on the blog landing page for Farro and Haute. If you uncheck Enable Ajax Loading in these templates, they
>   will still use Ajax to load the Blog Page.
>
> To enable or disable Ajax:
>
> - In the Home Menu, click Design, and then click Style Editor.
> - Scroll down to Site: Loading.
> - Check or uncheck Enable Ajax Loading.

If you do not want to disable AJAX, then [see "Option 2" here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492245/54493314#54493314) for how to write your code so that it will work on initial page load and on AJAX page loads.

Comment: Brandon, I can't thank you enough! I'm am not familiar with AJAX, so I guess that's something I learn a little better. This was exactly my issue. Thank you so so much!

Comment: @Tess, glad to hear it. Please don't forget to accept/upvote correct answers here on StackOverflow.