# How to rewrite javascript to force it to load despite Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, squarespace

I have the following javascript code, the problem is that the Squarespace site i'm working on requires Ajax-loading. Therefore, this code only works if you refresh the page once loaded. More on this issue here https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/87058-why-doesnt-my-javascript-code-work-until-i-refresh-the-page/

I'd be grateful for any pointers on how to rewrite this so that it loads despite the Ajax. It works wonderfully when I disable Ajax but unfortunately I need for that to be turned on for the rest of the site to look good.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> $(document).ready(function(){
$('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3').css('cursor','pointer');
$(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3").nextUntil("h3").slideToggle();
$(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3").click(function()
{$(this).nextUntil("h3").slideToggle();}); }); </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: This looks very promising but I have no idea how to switch up my code in order to use it.

Comment: @cloned That only helps for events but won't affect the css() or slideToggle() shown

Comment: How is your ajax done? Need to call some of this after it completes when the elements actually exist

Comment: The CSS should be set in CSS anyhow and not via jQuery. The slidetoggle needs to be called once the loading of the data finished, but we don't know how this is done.

Comment: Thanks folks, here's the template for you to evaluate the Ajax: https://brine-demo.squarespace.com/

Comment: Show us the code. We shouldn't have to go dig through a remote site

Comment: @charlietfl I agree but I don't know what the code is myself :) Then I guess you can't help me but thank you for your efforts so far!

Comment: See: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue, and [there are several common ways that developers approach the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493314/5338581).

In your case, inserted via [sitewide code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
  $('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3').css('cursor','pointer');
  $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3").nextUntil("h3").slideToggle();
  $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("h3").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
```